# How to programmaticaly remove sort row in Excel?

Tags: excel

i have constructed a pivot table and applied a style to it.

[image: Constructed Table]

The code I used for styling:
- created a range, filled with data and then:

```
_activeWorksheet.ListObjects[tableName].TableStyle = TableStyleToUseForRender;
```

Now. as it is a pivot table, i dont' need that sorting row, how do I remove it/disable programmatically?

thank you,
HF

Comment: Is this written in C#.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh well..  after playing around with that freaking filter row i found the way, sort of, to disable it .. converting the dropdowns into the string 'column titles'.

The way to do it is .. he he.. to select the filter row and apply autofilter as many times as there are the columns:

```
Range firstRow = worksheetCellsRange.Rows[1];
                firstRow.AutoFilter(1,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    false);
                firstRow.AutoFilter(2,
                                   Type.Missing,
                                   XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd,
                                   Type.Missing,
                                   false);
                firstRow.AutoFilter(3,
                                   Type.Missing,
                                   XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd,
                                   Type.Missing,
                                   false);
```

so, you can see that I am going through 1,2,3 column .. and vu'a la.. you have disable the dropdowns..   Hope it helps. .thanks!